# Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Duplicate entry 'CC2-2012-04-10-201205' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

We have a C# app that has been working on three machines, 2 running Mono and 1 running Windows succesfully for the last 4 years.

Recently, we had a crash and updated the Windows machine while doing the repair. MySql on the machine is 5.5.16

Post the update, the app is now throwing the error in the title "Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Duplicate entry 'CC2-2012-04-10-201205' for key 'PRIMARY'"

- None of the fields are auto-incremented
- We are using a DbDataAdapter
- The sql statement is an UPDATE
- All the indexes, table strucutures, privileges etc appear to be the same across all servers
- There are no triggers on the tables
- We have dropped and repaired the tables and indexes over and over to no avail
- We have tried MyIASM and InnoDB (We initially used InnoDB)

I have no idea how an update statement can fail with a duplicate key, about the nearest solution I have found was a MySql error many, many versions ago here:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27650
But that was repaired many years ago apparently.

Anyone have any ideas where I can look next?

Comment: How update statement can fail with a duplicate key? `insert into T id,val values (1,1), (2,2)` then `update T set id=2 where id=1`, having `T.id` as pkey.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the app still runs as expected on the 2 Mono machines with the older version of MySQL.  The way you have phrased the question suggests that you think the upgrade is the culprit.  Is there a chance you can rollback the MySQL upgrade on the Windows box; or upgrade only 1 of the Mono machines to find out if you can reproduce the problem there?

Comment: I've asked the guy with access to the machine to try a roll back. I doubt the version of SQL actually has a bug in it else others would be seeing it... Most likely we have mucked something up with the settings but I can't think what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a version mismatch between the ADO.NET Driver for MySQL (Connector/NET) and the MySQL server version. Pretty obvious really.

The ADO driver we were using turned out to be a fairly old version, and there must have been some major changes in the meanwhile.

Simply upgrading the mysql.data.dll fixed everything up

EDIT: Confirmed, we were using a very old MySql.Data ADO.NET driver version 1.0.10.1 
This worked with MySql server 5.1.53 and below. (This was the highest server version we had where our code still worked)

Once we upgraded to MySql server version 5.5.24 the apps all began failing with the DataAdapter excepting out with duplicate records (where there were none)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Didn't work for me, but heres a compatability matrix for others. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html